# Wicket datatable propertycolumn

Tags: java, datatable, wicket

I'm getting a NPE when trying to add a column with the sort attribute specified. Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

This is the class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="checklist_template")
public class CheckListTemplate extends DomainObject implements Comparable<CheckListTemplate>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2959377496669050427L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    public CheckListTemplate() {}

    public CheckListTemplate(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //some other attributes, getters, setters etc

}
```

This is the code:

```
public class CheckListTemplateDataPanel extends Panel {

    @SpringBean
    public ChecklistTemplateService checklistTemplateService;

    DataTable<CheckListTemplate> table;
    NavigationToolbar navigationToolbar;
    ChecklistTemplateProvider checklistTemplateProvider;

    public CheckListTemplateDataPanel(String id) {
        super(id);

        IColumn[] columns = new IColumn[1];

        columns[0] = new PropertyColumn<CheckListTemplate>(Model.of("Name"), "name", "name"); //this is what generates the exception. if i ignore the third argument, the code works but i get no link to click for sorting

        table = new DataTable<CheckListTemplate>("datatable", columns, checklistTemplateProvider =  new ChecklistTemplateProvider(), 10);
        table.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        table.addBottomToolbar(navigationToolbar = new NavigationToolbar(table));
        table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, null));
        add(table);

    }

    private class ChecklistTemplateProvider extends SortableDataProvider<CheckListTemplate> {

        public ChecklistTemplateProvider() {
            setSort("name", true);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<? extends CheckListTemplate> iterator(int first, int count) {
            return checklistTemplateService.findAll(new PageRequest(table.getCurrentPage(), count)).iterator();

        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return safeLongToInt(checklistTemplateService.count());
        }

        @Override
        public IModel<CheckListTemplate> model(CheckListTemplate object) {
            return Model.of(object);
        }

        public void setFilterString(String filterString){
            this.filterString = filterString;
        }
    }

    public static int safeLongToInt(long l) {
        if (l < Integer.MIN_VALUE || l > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                    (l + " cannot be cast to int without changing its value.");
        }
        return (int) l;
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
2012 May 03 13:58:58,480[ERROR] - RequestCycle - Exception in rendering component: [MarkupContainer [Component id = header]]
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [MarkupContainer [Component id = header]]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2729)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1441)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.renderChild(AbstractRepeater.java:122)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onRender(AbstractRepeater.java:103)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1441)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:697)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.onComponentTagBody(Panel.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.DataTable$ToolbarContainer.onRender(DataTable.java:429)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.renderChild(AbstractRepeater.java:122)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onRender(AbstractRepeater.java:103)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1441)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:697)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.onComponentTagBody(Panel.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1441)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:697)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.onComponentTagBody(Panel.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1441)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1445)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1445)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1445)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1445)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1445)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1604)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2690)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.autoAdd(MarkupContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.MarkupInheritanceResolver.resolve(MarkupInheritanceResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.ComponentResolvers.resolve(ComponentResolvers.java:81)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1445)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1555)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:1594)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2521)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:932)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.respond(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.sort.OrderByLink$CssModifier.onComponentTag(OrderByLink.java:208)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponentTag(Component.java:4270)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2681)
    ... 125 more
```

Comment: Try to attach a debugger in the Wicket source at the line specified by the error `OrderByLink:208` you will be able to narrow down your problem. Is your getter doing any nasty thing ? Can your `findAll()` return null values ?

Comment: What happens in checklistTemplateService.findAll()? And what parameter do you pass in? Also, I would not have a public constructor in your domain class if the name is a required attribute.

Comment: quickstart: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1122984/myproject.zip

@bert findAll just returns all objects of this class from the DB. It doesnt return null or anything like that. Like I said, everything works just fine if I dont send that third argument, so thats where the issue is. The empty constructor is there for other reasons (spring, hibernate etc) but thanks for the heads up and you attention to detail.

Comment: @CedricGatay I tried debugging but got none the wiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, null));
```

You have to provide the instance of your DataProvider instead of `null` in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it, thanks to the attached myproject.zip code.

```
table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, null));
```

is the line that cause the problem, you have to pass a ISortStateLocator to the `HeadersToolbar` class.

Comment: Big thanks mate, Chris got it literally seconds before you did, wish I could mark both as the correct answer!

Comment: No problem, I found out debugging your code, I put a simple breakpoint on the concerned line, saw that stateLocator was null, put another one in the class constructor and read the call stack. If the procedure can help you find another future bug...

Comment: I will make sure to try it in the future if I run into similar problems. Its the first time Ive seen this kind of deeper debugging, thanks for the explanation!